# Reverse Repo and Yield to maturity

Tags: yield, repo

there is one question I got wrong that I am confused about and that is the following :
If you believe that yield will increase in the future which of the following should you choose?
the two possibilities are.

A )REPO
B )REVERSE REPO

I answered REPO because if the yield goes up this means that price goes down and by choosing a REPO(A repurchase agreement (repo) is an agreement to sell some securities to
another party and buy them back at a fixed date and for a fixed amount.   by P.Veronesi)
we will sell securities at an higher price and buy back at a lower price
Could someone , please,explaine  why the correct answer is REVERSE REPO?

Comment: Did you get the question wrong because your answer was wrong or your rationale was wrong?

Comment: my answer was wrong ( the correct answer is REVERSE REPO) but I don't understand why     Because from my understanding if the yield goes up the price goes down what we should do is a REPO ,that is sell today and buy back tommorrow (when the price goes down because my expectation is an increase in the yield and consequently a decrease in price) .What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure why your answer is wrong. But your rationale is not quite right.  As the repo party is borrowing money (lending collateral) they would want to borrow funds at a lower rate. The prices to sell and repurchase the security is fixed at the time of the transaction to reflect the interest rate charge. If rates are going up, I would suspect as a borrower of money (not securities) they would want to repo. However, if you look at the market screens, they are looking at it from the dealer perspective--Repo is dealer lends collateral/securities and Rev Repo is where the dealer borrows collateral

Comment: That may be the source of your mistake, the person asking the question may be looking at it from the market convention perspective rather than the end user perspective.  This is a point of confusion all the time since the Repo and the Rev Repo is on opposite sides of the same trade.  It is always best to clarify whose perspective are you defining as Repo/Rev Repo.  The Repo party is borrowing money and lending securities.  But if you go to the market and have cash to invest, you go to the Repo market even though the dealer is repo, and you are rev repo.

Comment: So the way the screens are set up on say Bloomberg, they show a market in Rev Repo with the bid and ask.  The ask is where they are borrowing money/lending securities and the rate will be lower.  The bid is where they are lending money/borrowing securities and the rate will be higher.